# onclick not calling javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, onclick

I'm having a simple issue with calling a javascript function.  I've been playing with this for hours and I can't see the problem.  Hopefully another perspective can help.

in the  of my php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showShareDiv(objid){
    var div = document.getElementById('share'+objid);
    if (div.style.display=='none'){
        div.style.display='block';
    }
    else{
        div.style.display='none');
    }
}
</script>
```

This is just to show/hide a div with name "share"+number (eg. share104).  When I look at the source the $obj->id correctly names the div and function onclick name.

Here is the button:

```
<div id="sharebutton" style="width:100%;" onclick="showShareDiv('<?=$obj->id?>');">
  <center>Share</center>
</div>
<div id="share<?=$obj->id?>" style="display:none;">
  SHARE BUTTONS GO HERE
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an extra `)`

```
function showShareDiv(objid){
    var div = document.getElementById('share'+objid);
    if (div.style.display=='none'){
        div.style.display='block';
    }
    else{
        div.style.display='none'; //had a `)` here
    }
}
```

Now it works: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/eHMZR/

Comment: Popping up the javascript console (shift-ctrl-J in firefox/chrome) would reveal the syntax error.

Comment: @MarcB -- and that is how i found it ^_^

Comment: Yep. Seems to be a common trend here for people to fly blind and blindfolded, never bothering to try the logging systems available to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Also for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an alert('test') in function, to see if function is called.